# How to add a checkbox column in a gridpanel in ExtJS3.4

Tags: extjs, extjs3

want to add a checkbox column in a gridpanel this.

I tried this.

```
var sm = Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel');
```

and in grid I am configuring this. `selModel: sm,`

Can any one help me in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Please follow this code
    I am sure this code is working fine.

     var sm = new Ext.grid.CheckboxSelectionModel({
                width: 25,
                singleSelect: true,
                header: ''
            });


     xtype: 'grid',
     sm: sm,
     store: store,
     trackMouseOver: true,
     cm: new Ext.grid.ColumnModel({
     defaultSortable: true,
         columns: [
              sm,
          { dataIndex: 'record', header: 'Record' },


                      ]
})
```

Comment: I am generating my column dynamically. Getting column from xml.